# How to get jsonp data with "401 Unauthorize" status?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

How to get jsonp data with "401 Unauthorize" status.

This is my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Script</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Script</h1>
<pre id="output">Loading…</pre>
<script>
function getcode(data) {
var data = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = data;
}
</script>
<script src="https://localhost:7783/track?callback=getcode"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code working great when I try to get data with "HTTP 200" status.

Example response 401:

```html
HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
Date: Sun, 08 Nov 2015 10:43:21 GMT

getcode({"track":"4632874-423423-42342343123-32132131-432-43242-4324"})
```

So the question is:
How to get jsonp data when status is 401 unauthorize ? I want to get this "getcode({"track":"4632874-423423-42342343123-32132131-432-43242-4324"})" ?

Thank you for help.

Comment: an XMLHttpRequest (or fetch) will be able to read that value as long as there's no CORS issues (but wont execute the callback, you could `eval` the response)

Comment: Is there any option that will bypass cors and get resonse with HTTP 401 status ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Browsers don't execute scripts when they are delivered with an HTTP error status.

Switch to XMLHttpRequest (and CORS if you need cross-origin support) instead. JSONP is a hack introduced to get around the same origin policy and, since it is a hack, has many limitations. CORS is a standard, properly thought out solution to the problem and has far fewer limitations.